# How long will the mechanical components of a camera last?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d750, camera

When walking around with my camera, I find myself using it as a fidget toy.  I open and close the memory card slot on my D750 or turn the aperture ring on my Voightlander manual focus lens.  My question is how many actuations are these components rated for? Will my camera be obsolete before they fail?

Comment: Why not buy a combination padlock & play with that instead? Whole lot cheaper & who cares if it wears out.

Comment: There's no way to tell from your "fidget toy" description *how much* you're fidgeting with the camera, so no way to predict when you'll break something. A camera like a D750 will last plenty long if you treat it right; less so if you abuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I open and close the memory card slot on my D750

I'd consider this the least robust item you could choose on that camera.  This is a habit I'd suggest you break.

> or turn the aperture ring on my Voightlander manual focus lens.

You'll be too arthritic to turn it before it gives in, IMO.  But why test that ?

> My question is how many actuations are these components rated for ?

Neither will likely have a rated life expectancy.

> Will my camera be obsolete before they fail?

Impossible to say as "obsolete" is a personal viewpoint.

Your camera's shutter has a rated lifetime of (AFAIK) about 150,000 shots.

The door on the memory will likely fail a lot sooner if you keep messing with it.  The lens will likely outlast you if you treat it well.

Learn to fiddle with your keys like a normal adult. :-)